# Sum dictionary without sum function

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, sum

```
stock={'meat':100,'fish':100,'bread':100, 'milk':100,'chips':100}


totalstock = sum(stock.values())
print("Total stock level :",totalstock)

totalstock=0
for value in stock :
totalstock = totalstock + value

print("Total stock level :",totalstock)
```

output : total stock level : 500

above is what i have so far^

I have been trying to figure how to sum up my dictionary without having to use a sum function perhaps using a for loop. I was hoping to get some help with it.

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code using `sum()` is the best way to do this, and I would recommend keeping things as-is. However, just for illustrative purposes, here's a for-loop method that does the same thing.

```py
stock = {'meat': 100, 'fish': 100, 'bread': 100, 'milk': 100, 'chips': 100}

totalstock = 0
for item, value in stock.items():
    totalstock += value

print(f"Total stock level: {totalstock}")
```

**Note**: I intentionally used [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) here as it's almost always more useful when iterating over dictionaries. If you *really* only need the values from a dict, it's more efficient to use [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

Answer (score 2):

```
stock = {'meat':100,'fish':100,'bread':100, 'milk':100,'chips':100}
total = 0

for v in stock.values():
    total += v
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> stock={'meat':100,'fish':100,'bread':100, 'milk':100,'chips':100}
>>> print(f"Total stock level  : {mean(stock.values())*len(stock)}")
Total stock level  : 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can iterate threw a dictonary in python very easily.

```
for key in dict:
    print(key)
```

So in your case you should do the following:

```
totalstock = 0
for key in stock:
    totalstock += stock[key]
print(totalstock)
```

Comment: I would recommend against this approach. This has to access the dict twice. It's better to iterate using `dict.values()` or `dict.items()`